# Parse HTML using Kanna

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm having issues trying to pull an image URL using [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna). I'm trying to grab "data-high-quality" from here:

```
<div class="cui-content c-bdr-gray-clr ch-bdr-gray-md ">

  <div class="cui-udc-image-container">
    <div class="cui-udc-image-overlay"></div>
        <div class="cui-image-lazy-container cui-image-hover-zoom">
    <img class="cui-svg-placeholder c-bg-gray-bg" type="image/svg+xml" height="250"  width="414" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' height='250' width='414'%2F%3E" alt="image placeholder">

    <img class="cui-image  lazy-wl    progressive-load  "
    src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' height='250' width='414'%2F%3E"
    data-original="//img.grouponcdn.com/deal/2LXY5HUANHJq7xXm3P5gNFJYBRB5/2L-1100x660/v1/c125x75q5.jpg"
    data-high-quality="//img.grouponcdn.com/deal/2LXY5HUANHJq7xXm3P5gNFJYBRB5/2L-1100x660/v1/c414x250q85.jpg"
    data-high-quality-2x="//img.grouponcdn.com/deal/2LXY5HUANHJq7xXm3P5gNFJYBRB5/2L-1100x660/v1/c414x250q85.jpg"
    alt="image for Up to 36% Off Las Vegas Margarita Mojito Festival">
  </div>
```

I'm only able to grab information from the first "img" element but the information I need is contained in the second one. My code looks like this:

```
func parseHtml(html: String) {
    var tempArray = [String]()

    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html:html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {

        for name in doc.css("div[class^='cui-image-lazy-container cui-image-hover-zoom']"){
            let imageUrl = (name.at_xpath("img")?["data-high-quality"])
            tempArray.append(imageUrl!)
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I'm supposed to grab the actual "img" node by it's class and then individually select which part of the HTML tag I'm looking for like this:

```
for name in doc.css("img[class='cui-image  lazy-wl    progressive-load  ']"){

            tempArray.append(name["data-high-quality"]!)
        }
```

Hope that helps anyone that runs into the same issue.